# Filter Array based on the Filtering of Another Object having Multiple array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. i want to filter array based the object has the condition.

my array is as follow :

```
var data = [
{
  "name": "nitin",
  "r_id": "1",
  "t_id": "4"
},
{
 "name": "test",
  "r_id": "2",
  "t_id": "3"
},
{
  "name": "test1",
  "r_id": "2",
  "t_id": "4"
},
{
  "name": "test3",
  "r_id": "3",
  "t_id": "3"
},
{
  "name": "test2",
  "r_id": "1",
  "t_id": "1"
}]
```

and my object is as follows :

```
var obj = {
role:['1','2'],
type:['1','3']
}
```

where r_id is the role id and t_id is the type id

so i want the results whose role id is in 1 or 2 AND type id is in 1 or 3.

so mathematically role_id && type_id ((1||2)&&(1||3))

my output should like:

```
var result = [
{
  'name':'test',
  'r_id':2,
  't_id':3,
},
{
  'name':'test2',
  'r_id':1,
  't_id':1,
}];
```

Comment: do you have tried something?

Comment: So how do you check if a value is in an array? How do you use filter? Answer those and sounds like you will be closer to the answer.

Comment: ya i have tried first take object then do foreach of each array then inside of it  i have did foreach of my user array but not getting any output.. so confuse about to get result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [
{
  "name": "nitin",
  "r_id": "1",
  "t_id": "4"
},
{
 "name": "test",
  "r_id": "2",
  "t_id": "3"
},
{
  "name": "test1",
  "r_id": "2",
  "t_id": "4"
},
{
  "name": "test3",
  "r_id": "3",
  "t_id": "3"
},
{
  "name": "test2",
  "r_id": "1",
  "t_id": "1"
}]

var obj = {
role:['1','2'],
type:['1','3']
}

let result = data.filter(item=>{
 return obj.role.indexOf(item.r_id) > -1 && obj.type.indexOf(item.t_id) > -1
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate your `data` and see if the keys (`r_id` and `t_id`) are present in the `obj` (in the respective arrays). For this you can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var data = [{"name":"nitin","r_id":"1","t_id":"4"},{"name":"test","r_id":"2","t_id":"3"},{"name":"test1","r_id":"2","t_id":"4"},{"name":"test3","r_id":"3","t_id":"3"},{"name":"test2","r_id":"1","t_id":"1"}]

var obj = {
  role:['1','2'],
  type:['1','3']
}

var result = data.filter(function(element){
    return obj.role.indexOf(element.r_id) !== -1 && // element has valid role
           obj.type.indexOf(element.t_id) !== -1 // element has valid type
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
{
  "name": "nitin",
  "r_id": "1",
  "t_id": "4"
},
{
 "name": "test",
  "r_id": "2",
  "t_id": "3"
},
{
  "name": "test1",
  "r_id": "2",
  "t_id": "4"
},
{
  "name": "test3",
  "r_id": "3",
  "t_id": "3"
},
{
  "name": "test2",
  "r_id": "1",
  "t_id": "1"
}]

var obj = {
role:['1','2'],
type:['1','3']
}

var filterItems = data.filter(function(o){ 
   return obj.role.indexOf(o.r_id) != -1  && obj.type.indexOf(o.t_id) != -1; });

console.log(filterItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change `obj` a bit, for corresponding property names in the data, you have, then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for wanted item.

```js
var data = [{ name: "nitin", r_id: "1", t_id: "4" }, { name: "test", r_id: "2", t_id: "3" }, { name: "test1", r_id: "2", t_id: "4" }, { name: "test3", r_id: "3", t_id: "3" }, { name: "test2", r_id: "1", t_id: "1" }],
    obj = { r_id: ['1', '2'], t_id: ['1', '3'] },
    keys = Object.keys(obj),
    result = data.filter(function (o) {
        return keys.every(function (k) {
            return obj[k].indexOf(o[k]) !== -1;
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```